# How to remote connect to SQL server via php website

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, remote-access

I have a laravel website and a MySQL database for it.

My website has few users, and any user has a SQL database on his computer and that database has the same name, same password, and same configuration.

Now I want my user login to my website and via website information, make changes to his SQL database on his computer.

How can I do this?
How can I connect to any SQL database on user's computer by my website?

Comment: I am really glad that *no one* can do that.

Comment: I hope to find a way

Comment: Are the user machines on the same network as your web server? Do the user machines have some way of securing themselves against attacks from the outside?

Comment: This sounds like a pretty big [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the original requirement you're trying to fulfill, which made you go _"I have to access a SQL database installed on my site's visitor's machines"_? Do they have some sort of application installed which maintains its own database? Why aren't those databases on a centralized server? How are they backed up? Doesn't the application have an API? And so on.

Comment: @neville-kuyt no, every user machines is on his personal pc without any network connection. but all database configuration is the same.

Comment: @CodeCaster All of these databases are owned by our own company. But we can not now create a centralized database in another way. Due to financial constraints

Comment: That answers exactly zero of my questions.

Comment: Your PCs don't have a network connection? In that case, how are they accessing your website?

Comment: @neville-kuyt My users are only connected to the Internet for a moment and should update their database at the same time through my site.

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to feed a SQL database through a website.

Comment: @codecaster Yes, every PC has a single software that manages that database, but due to the financial constraint, we are not able to integrate these databases at present, and they are not centralized.Their backup is manual and irregular. There is no API. In fact, the database is very simple, but unfortunately, important information is stored on it and this is a problem for the company I work for. But that's what it is.

Comment: Voting to close - your question is just not clear enough for anyone to write a sensible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is that if you know the details of your users' machines, you can create connection strings for them in your config file, and use those connections to open MySQL sessions on the client machines - see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database, section "Using Multiple Database Connections".

This assumes all the machines are accessible from your server - presumably because they are on the same, local, non-internet-accessible network.

If your user's machines are accessible from the Internet, please do not do this - they will get hacked. It's a question of "when", not "if".

It's also a pretty horrible solution from an application architecture point of view - presumably the databases on the users' machines expect certain things about the database to be true, and your application would have to guarantee all those things. For instance, your application might expect "all orders have a valid customer; all customers have a valid country code". That's hard enough to guarantee on a single database, but on a distributed system, it's really hard.

It's much better to use MySQL [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) for scenarios like this.